# iPhone default email address not used for new emails

Tags: iphone, email, mobile-mail

I have three email accounts setup. I have one of my personal accounts as my default. Whenever I compose a NEW email it automatically populates my work email address - doesn’t matter what mailbox I might be in.  I’ve tried to change my default account and every single time the from address is my work email!

Comment: Are all your email addresses associated with your contact in contact list ?

Comment: @ankii please don't edit minor things if the question as a whole remains in need of details. The question won't show up in the review queue a second time.

Comment: @nohillside I am aware of that, but this barely needs anything else! I don't think even iOS version would help, except for a possible bug fix. Closing just because there's a sense of desperation is not good IMO. Rest all can be fixed via comments. \\ No-one even left a comment asking for anything.

Comment: @ankii The link in the notice gives some insights into how a question can be improved, even without comments.